# Asp.Net MVC and the use of Web API and/or Knockout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I'm about to start a new Asp.Net MVC development and I would like to make the best choices. In my previous MVC development I enjoyed a series of things like:

- views based on view models
- client side validation
- remote validation

I read a lot on the web concerning Web API and Knockout. I understand the principle of each but it seems to me that if I use one (or both) of these elements, I'll not be able to benefits of the advantages listed above.

My new dev will be mainly some lists based on search results, then CRUD operations on it.

I'd like your opinion on the use of Web API and/or Knockout on my new project. I know this is partly a subjective choice but the opinion of the community is important for me. Maybe have you already had to make these choices?

Thanks for your opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely no harm in using both WebAPI and knockout. knockout is just a client binding library and WebAPI is a service layer.

1. You can still create viewmodels that are returned from WebAPI.
2. You can still use MVC Controllers to return your views.
3. You can use knockout to manage your client side viewmodels and interactions.

A general approach (Please do read up a lot on WebAPI and model bindings in Web API) would be.

1. MVC Project -> Contains a controller that just serves views based on the requested action.
2. Web API -> Service layer for your business logic.
3. Modular Javascript (use requirejs, knockout and read about revealing module pattern in Javascript) to define your viewmodels (don't think of this as the viewmodels served by the API, these viewmodels will also define client side interactions, computed observables .etc)
4. Create a Binder JS module that will take in a viewmodel and bind to a DOM.

Things you need to know when you follow this approach.
1. If there are bindings on your Layout and any partials and you call ko.applyBindings(new vm()); you will see errors. Instead, bind to a particular div or element that will act as the container for your viewmodel data.
2. Web API model binders are different than ASP.Net MVC model bindings. Read up on this.
3. Separate out your Javascript files into smaller modules doing specific things and you can handle things better.

If you wish to learn more about this, look up Single Page Application using ASP.Net. The new release of ASP.Net and VS2012 update has SPA templates and lots of examples on using knockout/WebAPI and other libraries such as Ember, Angular .etc.

Hope that helps.

Cheers!